# Acces query works but when i try to make a report i get an error

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm having trouble with an SQL query in Microsoft Acces. I made the query in MYSQL after that I have put it in Microsoft Acces. This all works fine. I get the information that i requested in my query. But when i want to make an report of it in acces it gives me this Error:

Group by clause with more levels in subquery is not allowed.

I'm seriosly like why?? It works everywhere in acces except in the report function...

This is the query:

```
SELECT I.genre_name AS Genre, round(Count(I.movie_id)*100/(select count(*) FROM MovieGenre)) AS Percentage
FROM MovieGenre AS I
GROUP BY I.genre_name
ORDER BY Count(I.movie_id) DESC;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your query to this:

```
SELECT I.genre_name AS Genre, round(Count(I.movie_id)*100/DCount("movie_id","MovieGenre"))  AS Percentage
FROM MovieGenre AS I
GROUP BY I.genre_name
ORDER BY Count(I.movie_id) DESC;
```

[This Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10284438/multi-level-group-by-clause-not-allowed-in-subquery) has a good description of the "why".

Here is and [MSDN article for DCount](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa211471(v=office.11).aspx)

Comment: Hello Josh,Thank you for your help. I now understand the "why". I changed my query in acces and it worked!