# SUM in MS Access report is using all rows despite grouping

Tags: ms-access

I have an MS Access report that has these columns:

- Inventory Code
- Amount
- Location

Here is the query:

```
SELECT TOP 13 i.Code, i.Weight * i.Average_CWT / 100 as Amount, il.Location
FROM Inventory as i
LEFT JOIN Item_Location il ON i.Code = il.Item_Code
ORDER BY i.Code
```

The report is grouped by the Inventory Code, because there is a 1 to many join to get the locations (1 item can have many locations), so I just want to show the inventory item, the amount, and then under that group all of the locations, which I have here:

[image]

This grouping is working well, as you can see the last record shows 2 locations for 1 inventory code.

The issue arises when I try to add a `SUM` of the `Amounts` to the report header. The sum at the top of the image is actually slightly off. It should be 3,795.8175, but is showing as 3854.2405.

This is because the row at the bottom has 2 locations. So the SUM does not add up the amounts shown on the report; instead it calculates the sum based off the query, which returns 2 rows for that inventory item with 2 locations, instead of the 1 shown in the report. That's why the SUM is adding both the records values, each worth 58.423.

How can I get around this? Yes the join will return 2 rows since the location is different, but the amount should not be doubled. I've tried calculating the SUM as a subquery, and adding the field to the top of my report but got this error:

> `Multi-level group by not allowed`

I already ran through this and it won't fix my problem: [Multi-level GROUP BY clause not allowed in subquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10284438/multi-level-group-by-clause-not-allowed-in-subquery).

Any ideas on how to get the true sum of records when using grouping in an Access report?

Comment: There is no GROUPING of any sort in your SQL query. No Aggregate function in the SELECT clause, no GROUP BY. So the whole question is confusing. Show the actual data and the results you want

Comment: Instead of grouping and summing in report, join an aggregate query to detail data or group and sum on a main report and use a subreport for related details. Or use DSum domain aggregate function.

Comment: @ThomasG if you reread the question, you will see that I was talking about grouping being present in the report, as well as the SUM being in the report, not my query.

Comment: @June7 I don't think joining to an aggregate query to the detail data query would work, since the SUM(Amount) will be a standalone number, and the only way to join to the detail data query is on the Code. I'll look at the subreport/DSum. I'll have to add in a calculated field to my table if I want to use DSum since I don't think it's possible to run a calculation inside of DSum since `Amount = i.Weight * i.Average_CWT / 100`

Comment: What do you mean Sum(Amount) would be a 'standalone' number - aren't you grouping by Code? Yes, can run a calculation inside domain aggregate function. `DSum("Weight * Average_CWT / 100", "tableORqueryName", "Code='" & [Code] & "'")`.

Comment: @June7 `SUM(Amount)` is the sum of the amount for all inventory codes. I mentioned in the question that it's a 1 to many relationship. So in the Inventory table the Code values are unique - no need for grouping by code. Using DSum worked. If you add this as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible options:

1. Instead of grouping and summing in report, join an aggregate query to detail data
2. A main report with Inventory data as RecordSource and a subreport for related location details
3. DSum() domain aggregate function, calculations can occur within domain aggregate:
   `DSum("Weight * Average_CWT / 100", "tableORqueryName")`